# Strange tile missing in GeoServer (GeoWebCache)

Tags: geoserver, tiles, geowebcache, image-mosaic

I am using GeoServer to publish an image mosaic layer that contains 100-ish single-band geotiffs. When I use the `Seed/Truncate` function of GeoWebCache to cache the layer in the format of jpeg-png, it runs perfectly during the processing with no error or warning. However, some tiles missed as you can see from the gif when load the layer with WMTS protocol after the caching tasks finished.
[image: Loading image mosaic layer through WMTS]
The blank area in level 3 is not a nodata area in the original geotiff. It is also verfied in level 1, level 2 and level 4 tiles. (Actually, there are tiles missing in other areas in level 4.)
This phenomenon does not occur if I load the layer with WMS, in which method the tiles will be generated dynamically.

[image: Loading image mosaic layer through WMS]
Both WMTS and WMS tests are done with the preview functions of Geoserver. Why does this happen? Is there anything I can do to avoid this problem?

Additional information: The missing tiles in level 3 are actually generated but all in blank(transparent png).